# Error sideloading JSON for act-as-taggable tags using active-model-serializers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, acts-as-taggable-on, active-model-serializers

In a Ruby 2/Rails 4 app, I am trying to use acts-as-taggable-on in conjunction with active_model_serializers in order to create a JSON API that would output my tags along with other model parameters.

First some background/motivation for this issue: The JSON is being fed into ember/ember-data, which as of the time of this writing has removed support for embedded records in JSON.  There is a supposed fix in the [documentation](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/TRANSITION.md#embedded-records) about this, but I find it clumsy and also haven't actually gotten it to work.  Since I'm an Ember newbie and am a little more comfortable with Rails, I figure I'll try to solve the problem another way, by sideloading the tag record alongside the document record.  I like this solution better because it makes more sense for my application, but I can't get this to work either.

Here's an example: Let's say I have a Document model that is using acts-as-taggable-on:

```
class Document < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_taggable
  # other code omitted
```

I've set up the database with one document with one tag.  Now we consider the following cases:

**1. Full Object Embed**: With the following serializer:

```
class DocumentSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id
  has_many :tags
```

My JSON has the following format (using Rails 4 UUIDs):

```
{
  "documents": [
    {
      "id": "c41460fa-2427-11e3-8702-0800270f33f4",
      "tags": [
        {
          "id": "a33fc396-2428-11e3-8eeb-0800270f33f4",
          "name": "test"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

**2. ID Embed**: Using the serializer

```
class DocumentSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id
  has_many :tags, embed: :id
```

My JSON now looks like:

```
{
  "documents": [
    {
      "id": "c41460fa-2427-11e3-8702-0800270f33f4",
      "tag_ids": [
        "a33fc396-2428-11e3-8eeb-0800270f33f4"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

**3. ID Embed with Tags Sideloaded**: According to active_model_serializers documentation, I should be able to do

```
class DocumentSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id
  has_many :tags, embed: :id, include: true
```

but this doesn't work.  Instead, I get a NoMethodError:

```
undefined method `object' for #<ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag:0x007f258cf1db38>
```

I've tried searching for this problem but haven't found anything useful so far.  I also couldn't find any documentation on either gem regarding usage with the other gem.  My suspicion right now that it has something to do with how acts-as-taggable-on is implemented, that it's not a straightforward has_many relationship?  Is anybody able to offer some input on this issue?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can I ask you how to handle relationships with ember? How Can you add a tag to document? CreateRecord?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Fixed!  Turns out to sideload the tags, the corresponding serializer must be defined.  I did not know this, because the documentation seems to imply that having a serializer is optional, and some default will be used in the absence of one.  Apparently this is not the case if you wish to use the `include: true` option.  Key in sight came from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14106752/rails-ember-active-model-serializer-undefined-method-object-when-sideloadi?rq=1), thanks very much!

For completeness, I'll show what I did.  I created `tag_serializer.rb` with the following code:

```
module ActsAsTaggableOn
  class TagSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
    attributes :id, :name
  end
end
```

and now my JSON:

```
{
   "tags": [
      {
         "id": "a33fc396-2428-11e3-8eeb-0800270f33f4",
         "name": "test"
      }
   ],
   "documents": [
      {
         "id": "c41460fa-2427-11e3-8702-0800270f33f4",
         "tag_ids": [
            "a33fc396-2428-11e3-8eeb-0800270f33f4"
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: also, be sure to save `tag_serializer.rb` in `app/serializers/acts_as_taggable_on/tag_serializer.rb` so that Rails can autoload it

Comment: It works for me but I need to remove that module ActsAsTaggableOn