# How to display hasMany records in Ember.js template?

Tags: javascript, json, model, ember.js, ember-data

I have model defined like this:

```
App.Question = DS.Model.extend({   
    title: DS.attr( 'string' ),  
    answers: DS.hasMany('App.Answer') 
});

App.Answer = DS.Model.extend({   
    title: DS.attr( 'string' ),  
    wynikid: DS.attr( 'number' ) 
});
```

And get data from RESTAdapter that returns data like this:

```
{
    "questions": [
        {
            "id": 77,
            "title": "O której wstajesz?",
            "answers": [
                {
                    "id": 159,
                    "title": "O godzinie 6",
                    "wynikid": 57
                },
                {
                    "id": 160,
                    "title": "O godzinie 7",
                    "wynikid": 56
                },
                {
                    "id": 161,
                    "title": "O godzinie 12",
                    "wynikid": 55
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 76,
            "title": "Kot czy kominiarz?",
            "answers": [
                {
                    "id": 156,
                    "title": "Kocur",
                    "wynikid": 57
                },
                {
                    "id": 157,
                    "title": "Kominiarz",
                    "wynikid": 56
                },
                {
                    "id": 158,
                    "title": "Ani to ani to",
                    "wynikid": 55
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 75,
            "title": "Wybierz ulubione imię",
            "answers": [
                {
                    "id": 153,
                    "title": "Bożydar",
                    "wynikid": 57
                },
                {
                    "id": 154,
                    "title": "Aleksander",
                    "wynikid": 56
                },
                {
                    "id": 155,
                    "title": "Andrzej",
                    "wynikid": 55
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 74,
            "title": "Wybierz liczbę",
            "answers": [
                {
                    "id": 152,
                    "title": "Liczba 13",
                    "wynikid": 56
                },
                {
                    "id": 151,
                    "title": "Liczba 7",
                    "wynikid": 55
                },
                {
                    "id": 150,
                    "title": "Liczba 1",
                    "wynikid": 57
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 78,
            "title": "Ulubiona pora roku",
            "answers": [
                {
                    "id": 162,
                    "title": "To lato",
                    "wynikid": 57
                },
                {
                    "id": 163,
                    "title": "Jesień / Wiosna",
                    "wynikid": 56
                },
                {
                    "id": 164,
                    "title": "To zima",
                    "wynikid": 55
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Now what i would like to acomplish is to show a list like this:

```
O której wstajesz?
 O godzinie 6
 O godzinie 7
 ...
Kot czy kominiarz?
 ...
```

I've tried to use this in Ember.js template:

```
 {{#each controller}}

  {{title}}<br>

    {{#each answer in answers}}

    \t{{title}}<br>

    {{/each}}

  {{/each}}
```

And questions are displayed but answers arent. I don't have any error in console and JSONLint also does not see any problems with JSON.

How to make it work?

I use:

handlebars1.0.0.0.js
ember-1.0.0.0.min.js
ember data: v0.13-238-gbf84978

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The newest version of ember/ember-data does not support embedded records.  This is documented [here](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/TRANSITION.md#embedded-records), but I found the workaround to be very clumsy and couldn't get it to work myself.

Maybe the best solution is to sideload your answers record so that it appears alongside the questions record in your JSON root.  This is of course assuming that you have control over your JSON format, so this answer does not apply if this is not the case.  If you are using active-model-serializers, this is done via the options `embed: :id` and `include: true`.  You would have a `question_serializer.rb` with something like

```
class QuestionSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :title
  has_many :answers, embed: :id, include: true
end
```

And also an `answer_serializer.rb` with something like

```
class AnswerSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :title, :wynikid
end
```

I believe it should then work.  I was having an issue with this just yesterday and posted a stackoverflow question on it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19564899/error-sideloading-json-for-act-as-taggable-tags-using-active-model-serializers/19577901#19577901), but I figured out my issue earlier today and answered my own question.  I was able to get a printout of my JSON in basically the same way you are trying to do with your handlebars code!

Edit: grammar.

Answer (score 0):

latest ember does not support embedded records out of box. but you can parse embedded by hand

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/AkovAPu/4 - example (will work if localhost:8888/questions return your json - { "questions": [...)

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/AkovAPu/4/edit - source (look at extractArray)